# how to insert data into array without replacing previous data

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to insert data into an array, I want it to add the new data without replacing the previous data

I'm trying to use `array_push` but it still replaces the previous data.

```
<?php
if (isset ($_POST['submit']; )) {

$num = 0.5;


$data[] = array(
  'no1' => $_POST['no1'],
  'no2' => $_POST['no2'],
  'no3' => $_POST['no3']
    );
array_push($data, array(
'no1' => $_POST['no1'],
'no2' => $_POST['no2'],
'no3' => $_POST['no3']
));
}
?>
```

and this is the form

```
<h4>Add data</h4>
<form class="" action="" method="post">
<ul>
<li>
  <label for="ni1">No 1 :</label>
  <input type="number" id="no1" name="no1" value="">
</li>
<li>
  <label for="ni1">No 2 :</label>
  <input type="number" id="no2" name="no2" value="">
</li>
<li>
  <label for="ni1">No 3 :</label>
  <input type="number" id="no3" name="no3" value="">
</li>
</ul>
<button type="submit" name="submit">ADD</button>
</form>
<table border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>No 1</td>
<td>No 2</td>
<td>No 3</td>
</tr>
<?php foreach ($data as $n): ?>
<tr>
  <td><?= $n['no1']* $num ?></td>
  <td><?= $n['no2']* $num ?></td>
  <td><?= $n['no3']* $num ?></td>
 </tr>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

I expect the new data inserted not replacing the previous data and showed into the table

Comment: `$data` is not persisted, it'll just be an empty array every time you execute your PHP script. You'll want to store that into the session, or into a database, for instance.

Comment: @jeto can i use session without login?

Comment: Yes, no need for a login system. See [the reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php). Note that as their name implies, they will only persist for the duration of the said session (usually until the person closes its browser or when the session expires). If you want to store data for a longer period of time, you should use a database instead.

Comment: Another alternative to using session is you could have a hidden field in your form - previous_data and store the current numbers into that array.

    <input type="hidden" id="previous_numbers" name="previous_numbers" value="<?=json_encode($_POST['previous_data']);?>">

Please note that there is a syntax error in your this line - `if (isset ($_POST['submit']; )) {`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Push like this function for example:

```
 <?php
    $dataArray = array('Mathematics','Physics');
    array_push($dataArray,'Chemistry','Biology');
    print_r($dataArray);
 ?>
```

output:

```
Array ([0] => Mathematics [1] => Physics [2] => Chemistry [3] => Biology)
```